# What is the shortened version of "Did you forget something ?"

Tags: grammar

What is the shortened version of "Did you forget something ?" is it "Forget something ?" or "Forgot something ?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se] 

Comment: Either could be used. This question requires more context.

Answer (score 2):

It’s just “*Forget something?*”, because you’re skipping the *“Did you”* part.

And please don’t put spaces in front of terminal punctuation like that. :(

Comment: Thanks!...so I am assuming it is grammatically wrong to ask "Forgot something?"

Comment: @sreenath Well, it doesn’t sound too hot to my ear. You’d have to concoct a situation for it. Maybe though in something like “Forgot something, eh?” when somebody runs back into the house to get something.

Comment: Avoid using multiple punctuation marks consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be correct. *Did you forget something?* is a past tense construction. The past is expressed by *did*, the past tense of *do*.

*Forgot something?* also expresses past tense. This would be the correct shortened form to express the same concept as the original.

However, *Forget something?* is also a correct construction and would not strike the listener as odd if used in place of *Did you forget something?*

Also,it would be the preferred phrase if the questioner were showing the forgotten item to the person who had left it behind.